# Why does "info()" not work even though the "read" field changes?

Tags: javascript, factory

I have a factory function, where I am returning a Book Object. When I create an object of the Book and change a field value, this is not reflected in the method of the Object. Any idea why this may be happening?

```
const Book = (title, author, pages, read) => {
    const info = () => {
        if (read == true) {
            return `${title} by ${author} - ${pages} pages - already read`;
        } else {
            return `${title} by ${author} - ${pages} pages - not read yet`;
        }
    }
    return { title, author, pages, read, info }; 
}
```

I create a Book Object using `let book = Book(title, author, pages, read);`
And change the value of read by accessing the read field directly.
However, when I change the value of read, this is not reflected in the info method.

Comment: Show us how you are changing `read` as per [mre]

Comment: The read variable is copied by value, since it’s a primitive. The info function only has access to the argument, not the object you eventually return from Book(). This generally seems a very weird way to write this. If you want to mutate a field consider writing Book as a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object properties are not aliases for the variables, the variable values are used when creating the object.

To refer to the object properties, you need to use `this`.

And in order to have `this` refer to the object, you must use a traditional function rather than an arrow function.

```js
const Book = (title, author, pages, read) => {
    const info = function() {
        if (this.read) {
            return `${this.title} by ${this.author} - ${this.pages} pages - already read`;
        } else {
            return `${this.title} by ${this.author} - ${this.pages} pages - not read yet`;
        }
    }
    return { title, author, pages, read, info }; 
}

let b = Book("Title", "Author", 10, false);
console.log(b.info());

b.author = "New Author";
console.log(b.info());
```

Comment: "*To refer to the object properties, you need to use `this`.*" - or store the object in a variable and refer to that by name.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS, you'd most probably want to use a `class` here which simplifies working with objects by alot:

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
  }
   
  get info() {
    return `"${this.title}" by ${this.author} - ${this.pages} pages - ${this.read ? 'already read' : 'not read yet'}`
  }
}

let b = new Book("No Place To Hide", "Glenn Greenwald", 259, false);
console.log(b.info);

b.author = "G. Greenwald";
console.log(b.info);

b.read = true;
console.log(b.info);

// you can even test if b is a Book:
// (which you could not with a factory function)
console.log(b instanceof Book);
```